# Vaadin 14 LoginI18n with HTML labels?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

In a Vaadin 14 application there is a Login form (com.vaadin.flow.component.login.LoginForm). The application uses LoginI18n (`LoginI18n i18n = LoginI18n.createDefault();`) and sets the texts (e.g. `i18n.setAdditionalInformation("Some additional information");`).

That works fine.
Now I want to add some HTML (contact details with an email anchor) into that additional information.

But putting plain HTML into that setter results in showing the HTML (with all its tags and so on) in the login form.

I guess that I could operate at the loginform by using getElement() and exchange text at the HTML elements. But as there is this I18n mechanism I think that it would be the right thing to use it, even for some HTML.

Is there some convenient way of using HTML in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

As you could see in the Source code of LoginI18n additionalInformation is a simple string:

```
private String additionalInformation;
```

Comment: Yes, it is a simple string. And HTML is also representable by a simple string. So theoretically it could have been that I can set the additional Information to "Hello <a href='world.html'>World</a>" and give Vaadin a hint like myLoginForm.pleaseInterpretI18NStringsAsHtml(true) or something like that.

Comment: Vaadin escapes HTML mostly.